# Connecting phpmyadmin to local database created in mysqlworkbench

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

I have a bunch of tables and databases created in mysql workbench, but I don't know how to connect them to phpmyadmin. When I start phpmyadmin I get the following error:

```
Warning in .\libraries\dbi\DBIMysqli.php#556
mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given

Backtrace

.\libraries\dbi\DBIMysqli.php#556: mysqli_real_escape_string(
boolean false,
string '_',
)
.\libraries\DatabaseInterface.php#2735: PMA\libraries\dbi\DBIMysqli-
>escapeString(
boolean false,
string '_',
)
.\libraries\navigation\nodes\Node.php#449: PMA\libraries\DatabaseInterface-
>escapeString(string '_')
.\libraries\navigation\NavigationTree.php#289: 
PMA\libraries\navigation\nodes\Node->getData(
string 'databases',
integer 0,
string '',
)
.\libraries\navigation\NavigationTree.php#847: 
PMA\libraries\navigation\NavigationTree->_buildPath()
.\libraries\navigation\Navigation.php#45: 
PMA\libraries\navigation\NavigationTree->renderState()
.\libraries\Header.php#425: PMA\libraries\navigation\Navigation->getDisplay()
.\libraries\Response.php#260: PMA\libraries\Header->getDisplay()
.\libraries\Response.php#273: PMA\libraries\Response->_getDisplay()
.\libraries\Response.php#432: PMA\libraries\Response->_htmlResponse()
PMA\libraries\Response->response()
```

I am trying to host from IIS 8 win 2012 server r2...so I don't know how to fix this error as there is no config.inc file and is there a way to directly connect the tables I have created in workbench to phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both MySQL WorkBench and PHPMyAdmin are tools to use MySQL, that is, they connect to the RDBMS and provide a ui to simplify your work with it. So your tables are created in MySQL, not in MySQL WorkBench.

The actual error means that the connection to the RDBMS was unsuccessful. This is why `mysqli_real_escape`_string gets a boolean argument. You will need to make sure that you connect using the correct:

- host
- port
- username
- password

You will need to ensure everything is correct using the PHPMyAdmin [configuration](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html).